# PROTRACTOR getText() doesn't work

Tags: gettext, protractor

I'm trying to resolve one problem referred to protractor getText(). I have a code which finds successfully an element:

```
var $editTrigger = $('[ui-view="hcp"] .m-pane__control__trigger');
```

then execute a line that works too:

```
expect($editTrigger.getText()).toBe('BEARBEITEN');
```

but if I execute this

```
console.log('---> $expectTrigger' + $editTrigger.getText());
```

what I get it's: [object Object].

Why? Why don't I get 'BEARBEITEN'? This has happened to me several times and I don't know what do I do wrongly.

If you need more information to evaluated this case please feel free to ask for it. Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getText() is an promise. the console.log will be executed long before the value from getText is returned. If you write it like a promise it works.

```
$editTrigger.getText().then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
});
```

The expects work because they now they are working with a promise and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks you. Finally my tests are runnig correctly. Thanks again.